# Concatenating two nums to a display in a JS/HTML calc, only one num shows

Tags: javascript, html, string, concatenation, calc

So I'm a beginner to JS and HTML. I'm making a simple calculator that is stack based and has 4 operations [*, +, -, /] To use the calculator, you push the buttons like so: 7 push 8 push * and when the * is clicked, the final answer 56 is shown. So my calculator works fine for single digit numbers and operations but when I try to enter a number like 56 i start by hitting the button '5' and then i hit '6' but it doesn't show up in the display field where the number/answer is supposed to be outputted. I'm assuming this is an issue with concatenating but I also have no idea what more I could try fixing so that the second number shows up in the display and I can operate with a two digit number. Can someone please provide some solutions on how I can fix this? Below is my JS and HTML code:

```js
//declare stack:
let stack = [];
//initialize displayval to 0
let displayVal = '0';
let decimalFlag = false;
//flag for starting number

// //"The JavaScript input text property is used to set or return the value of a text input field":

const input = document.getElementById('result');

//function to display num in display element:
// function displayNum(val) {
//     if (input.value === "0") {
//         input.value = val;
//     } else {
//         input.value += val;
//     }

// }

function displayNum(val) {
  if (input.value === '') {
    input.value = val;
  } else {
    input.value += val;
  }
}

// //function to display num in display element:
// function displayNum(val) {
//     //let display = document.getElementById("result");
//     if (input.innerHTML === "0") {
//         input.innerHTML = val;
//     } else {
//         input.innerHTML += val;
//     }

// }

//Clears the display and sets to 0:
function clearScreen() {
  document.getElementById('result').value = '0';
  //clears stack:
  stack = [];
  displayVal = '0';
  //set start num to true  for all operations
}

// displays results after operations:
function display(val) {
  //setting display to 0 :
  if (val === 'Push') {
    stack.push(displayVal);
    //displayVal = "0";
    decimalFlag = false;
  }
  //else operations:
  else if (val === '+' || val === '-' || val === '*' || val === '/') {
    //popping nums off stack:
    let num2 = stack.pop();
    let num1 = stack.pop();

    //answer:
    let result;
    //converts strings to numbers to operate on them:

    //addition:
    if (val === '+') {
      result = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
      //console.log(result);
    }

    //subtraction:
    else if (val === '-') {
      result = Number(num1) - Number(num2);
    }

    //mult:
    else if (val === '*') {
      result = Number(num1) * Number(num2);
    }

    //division:
    else if (val === '/') {
      result = Number(num1) / Number(num2);
    } else {
      if (displayVal === '0') {
        displayVal = val;
      } else {
        displayVal += val;
      }
    }

    //push result to stack and display
    stack.push(result);
    //testing output:
    console.log(result);
    displayVal = result;
    decimalFlag = false;
  }

  //negates a number:
  else if (val === '+/-') {
    displayVal = displayVal[0] === '-' ? displayVal.slice(1) : '-' + displayVal;
  }

  //else, val is shown on the display
  else {
    displayVal = val;
  }

  document.getElementById('result').value = displayVal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  

  <!--create a table element to organize calc-->
  <table>
<!-- Create a row for the display -->
    <tr>
      <!--settining initial display value to 0-->
      <td colspan="4"><input class="display" type="number" id="result" disabled value = "0"/></td>
      <!--clear button will clear everything on display-->
      <!-- <td><input type="button" value="C" onclick="clr()" /> </td> -->
    </tr>
    <!-- Create the first row of buttons -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="display('1')" class="btn" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="display('2')" class="btn" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="display('3')" class="btn" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="display('+')"/></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Create the second row of buttons -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="display('4')" class="btn"/></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="display('5')" class="btn"/></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="display('6')" class="btn"/></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="display('-')"/></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Create the third row of buttons -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="display('7')" class="btn" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="display('8')" class="btn" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="display('9')" class="btn" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="*" onclick="display('*')"/></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Create the fourth row of buttons -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="0" onclick="display('0')" class="btn" /></td>
      <!--Clears screen and sets display val to 0-->
      <td><input type="button" value="C" onclick="clearScreen('C')" id="C"/> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="display('.')"/></td> <!--have to implement still-->
      <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="display('/')"/></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Create the fifth row of buttons -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="+/-" onclick="display('+/-')"/></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Push" onclick="display('Push')"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table> <!--end of table-->

<!-- script links to JS code-->
<script src="script.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

I tried a bunch of modifications to the displayNum function because i'm pretty sure that's where the issue is coming from. As u can see, I commented out my different approaches and there where plenty more but those are just 2

Comment: Hmm, it seems the `type=number` attribute of the `input` tag is messing stuff up. I believe the "concatenation" your doing is (by design) creating a string, not a number. Perhaps check out `parseInt` and remove the type attribute, or get inspiration from other calculator projects, that might have a more clever approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `display` function, you can update the following code:

```js
  //else, val is shown on the display
  else {
    // displayVal = val; // <= BEFORE
    displayVal = input.value === "0" ? val : input.value + val; // <= AFTER
  }
```

There's some more refactoring that you must do, in order for the arithmetic operations to work, but that's the next step I guess. :)

Comment: and then uncomment `//displayVal = "0";` in the first condition for `PUSH`

Comment: when u say refactoring to make the operations work, could u give me an example of how to refactor one of the operations so i can head in the right direction?

Comment: Just think about what has to be done, try out some code carefully, fail, refactor, fail again, refactor and boom! You have the working solution. It's always a cycle of thinking and trial and error in software development. It's better to fail and learn by the mistakes rather than get the 'right' direction from the start @adviNess. You'll learn a lot more through taking the 'wrong' directions. Good luck and enjoy the journey. :)